# ¿Cómo funciona data-toggle bootstrap 4 en dropdown menú?

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4, menú

Quiero tener dos dropdown menú en un sidebar, pero el problema es que me aparecen las mismas opciones en ambos:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es" >
  <head>
<title>BASICO</title>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico" />
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <!-- Fontawesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

<!-- Bootstrap  JS-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css" media="screen" />
  </head>
<div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">

<!-- Sidebar -->
<div class="bg-light border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar-heading">OPCIONES</div>
  <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"><i class="fas fa-search"></i><span  id="artmodal"> ARTICULO - F2</span>
  </a>

    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#miModals" href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"><i class="fas fa-wrench"></i><span  id="serv"> SERVICIO - F7</span></a>
    <a  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalCC" href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"> <i  class="fas fa-list"></i><span  id="CC"> CUENTAS   - F4</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"><i  class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i><span  id="VENTA"> VENTA   -   F6</span></a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light" href="#" id="navbarDropdowndatos" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-database"></i>
           DATOS
          </a>  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdowndatos">
   <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"><i class="fas fa-user"></i><span  id="user">USUARIOS</span>
</a>
 <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"><i class="fas fa-user"></i><span  id="cliente">CLIENTES</span>
</a>
 <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"><i class="fas fa-list-alt"></i><span  id="art">ARTICULOS</span>
</a>
 <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"><i class="fas fa-user"></i><span  id="prov">PROVEEDORES</span>
</a>
       
          </div>
 <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light" id="navbarDropdowncaja" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-cash-register"></i><span  id="art2">CAJA</span>
</a> <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdowncaja">
   <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"><i class="fas fa-cash-register"></i><span  id="estado">ESTADO</span>
</a>
 <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"><i class="fas fa-invoice-dollar"></i><span  id="cuentas">CUENTAS CORRIENTES</span>
</a>

       
          </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

<!-- Page Content -->
<div id="page-content-wrapper">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light border-bottom">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="menu-toggle"><i class="fas fa-sliders-h"></i></button>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1 class="mt-4">Simple Sidebar</h1>
    <p>The starting state of the menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will change.</p>
    <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>. The top navbar is optional, and just for demonstration. Just create an element with the <code>#menu-toggle</code> ID which will toggle the menu when clicked.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

  </div>
  <!-- /#wrapper -->

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->


  <!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
  <script>
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Es decir hacen referencia al mismo div de opciones supongo. ¿Cómo puedo hacer?, como veran tienen opciones distintas ambos divs.

Comment: Necesitaríamos ver tu Javascript, seguramente estés referenciando ambos dropdown con la misma clase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en como haces la llamada a cada uno de los dropdown en el list, creo que en este caso, ya que estás usando bootstrap como base, puede aprovecharte de sus estructuras para crear tu sidebar con dropdowns ya que de manera muy sencilla puedes replicar lo que ya tienes y te garantizas que funcionará todo correctamente sin que tengas que implementar más código. Te dejo un ejemplo de como puede quedar dentro de tu código, pero lógicamente sin cambiarle el estilo:

```js
        $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

    <div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div class="bg-light border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">
          <div class="sidebar-heading">OPCIONES</div>
          <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"><i class="fas fa-search"></i><span  id="artmodal"> ARTICULO - F2</span>
          </a>
        
            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#miModals" href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"><i class="fas fa-wrench"></i><span  id="serv"> SERVICIO - F7</span></a>
            <a  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalCC" href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"> <i  class="fas fa-list"></i><span  id="CC"> CUENTAS   - F4</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"><i  class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i><span  id="VENTA"> VENTA   -   F6</span></a>
              <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light" href="#" id="navbarDropdowndatos" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-database"></i>
                   DATOS
                  </a> 
                   <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdowndatos">
           <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"><i class="fas fa-user"></i><span  id="user">USUARIOS</span>
        </a>
         <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"><i class="fas fa-user"></i><span  id="cliente">CLIENTES</span>
        </a>
         <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"><i class="fas fa-list-alt"></i><span  id="art">ARTICULOS</span>
        </a>
         <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"><i class="fas fa-user"></i><span  id="prov">PROVEEDORES</span>
        </a>
               
                  </div>
         <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light" id="navbarDropdowncaja" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-cash-register"></i><span  id="art2">CAJA</span>
        </a> 
        
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdowncaja">
           <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"><i class="fas fa-cash-register"></i><span  id="estado">ESTADO</span>
        </a>
         <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"><i class="fas fa-invoice-dollar"></i><span  id="cuentas">CUENTAS CORRIENTES</span>
        </a>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Default dropup button -->
    <div class="btn-group dropup">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropup
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
          </div>
      </div>
      
      <!-- Split dropup button -->
      <div class="btn-group dropup">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">
          Split dropup
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action 2</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action 2</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here 2</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link 2</a>
          </div>
      </div>
       
    </div>
          </div>

          
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
        
        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light border-bottom">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="menu-toggle"><i class="fas fa-sliders-h"></i></button>
        
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown
                  </a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
        
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <h1 class="mt-4">Simple Sidebar</h1>
            <p>The starting state of the menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will change.</p>
            <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>. The top navbar is optional, and just for demonstration. Just create an element with the <code>#menu-toggle</code> ID which will toggle the menu when clicked.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
        
          </div>        </div>

          <!-- /#wrapper -->
        
          <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
        
        
          <!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
    

</body>
</html>
```

Además de dejo aquí en enlace a la [documentación de bootstrap para los dropdowns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/)